# Error while building jar file of Java derby project

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, build

I am trying to build a jar file of java derby project in netbeans, but I am facing this error.

> ant -f C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3
>   -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar init: deps-clean: Updating property file:
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\built-clean.properties
>   Deleting directory
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build
>   clean: init: deps-jar: Created dir:
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build
>   Updating property file:
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\built-jar.properties
>   Created dir:
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\classes
>   Created dir:
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\classes\META-INF
>   Copying 1 file to
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\classes\META-INF
>   Created dir:
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\empty
>   Created dir:
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
>   Compiling 3 source files to
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\classes
>   warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation
>   processor
>   'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor'
>   less than -source '1.8' Note: Creating non-static metadata factory ...
>   Note: Found Option : eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory,
>   with value: false Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml
>   continuing with generation. Note: Optional file was not found:
>   META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation. Note: Found
>   Option : eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory, with value:
>   false Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing
>   with generation. Note: Optional file was not found:
>   META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\src\javaapplication3\NewJFrame.java:8:
>   error: package com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet does not
>   exist import static
>   com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.table;
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\src\javaapplication3\NewJFrame.java:8:
>   error: static import only from classes and interfaces import static
>   com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.table;
>   warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor:
>   '[eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory]' 2 errors 1 warning
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:930:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:270:
>   Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details. BUILD
>   FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

How to solve this error? Although the program is successfully running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because of [this](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7159016) bug in Java, could you try changing

```
import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.table;
```

to

```
import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.*;
```

Comment: Bundle of thanks, this was an unnecessary import, I just deleted this line.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer as correct if it has helped you?

Comment: I am unable to see any option to mark this answer as correct, probably because my account is new here.

Comment: I found the tick to mark the answer as correct and have clicked it.